# How to get button value on click ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm having issue by getting button value. 
I need to get the Button value on click for sorting some data in php.

If i try some [examples](https://benmarshall.me/wordpress-ajax-frontend-backend/#ajax-frontend) everything works fine.

I don't know how i can get the the value from the clicked Button... 
I need this for sorting an array. Can somebody tell me how to get value of clicked button by ajax? 
Thanks for ideas..

This is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#button1").click(function () {
                var data = {
                    action: 'table_contest',
                    security : MyAjax.security,
                    sort: 1
                };

                // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
                $.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    //test
                    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                });
            });
});
```

In the php:

```
// Add the JS
function theme_name_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('custom-script', 'MyAjax', array(
        // URL to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to process the request
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        // generate a nonce with a unique ID "myajax-post-comment-nonce"
        // so that you can check it later when an AJAX request is sent
        'security' => wp_create_nonce('test')
    ));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts');


function table_contest_function($atts){

    check_ajax_referer('test', 'security');

    //get how to sort the tabledata
    $sort = intval($_POST['sort']);


    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'table-id'  => ''
        ), $atts );

    // get table data from Plugin TablePress
    $table = TablePress::$model_table->load( $atts['table-id'], true, true );

    //only get the important data
    $data = $table['data'];

//if button was clicked sort asc
    if ($sort == '1'){
        //sort
asort($data);
    }

    $output = ......;


    echo $output;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_table_contest', 'table_contest_function');
```

Comment: inside click function ... $(this).val() OR $(this).html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to get the clicked element using the this keyword, which gets you the current scope.

Check out the code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#button1").click(function () {
                var btn_val = $(this).val();
                var data = {
                    action: 'table_contest',
                    security : MyAjax.security,
                    sort: 1,
                    btn : btn_val

                };

                // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
                $.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    //test
                    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                });
            });
});
```